# Why am I getting a null from a parceleable

Tags: android, android-bundle

I am trying to get data from a parceleable of the next way:

First, create a Bundle of the following way:

```
final Bundle extras = new Bundle();
```

I set the data

```
extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_EXTRAS, data);
```

And in the other activity I try to get the data of the next way:

```
  public Connection onCreateIncomingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle, ConnectionRequest connectionRequest) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreateIncomingConnection");
        final Bundle bundle = connectionRequest.getExtras();

        final Data data = (Data) bundle.get(TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_EXTRAS);
```

But when I try to get the Data this is always null, but I check that this is not null when I set the data.

Any idea of why Data become to null?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

replace `.get` with `.getParcelable`